# Negotiating a shorter contract?

Tags: contracts

I am currently lining up an interview with a large corporation in NYC. I have an interview with a recruiter and a top executive, (who really wants me to work there).

I am currently on a month-to-month contract at a small start-up in Boston. I have been getting monthly reviews for the past two months and will be considered for a full time offer after this month but I fear that there is not enough for me to do here to take a full time offer.

What I would like to do is arrange for another short three month contract so I can stay here a little bit longer and then easily transfer to the other job.

If the start-up does not offer me a full time position can I try to arrange for this?
If the start-up DOES offer me a full time position can I still ask for three months only?

I just don't want to be unemployed during the transition process but I still don't want to leave Boston and the company after such a short period of time. It would be great if I could be secure in my future and knowing that I will have another job to go to after this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the startup does not offer me a full time position can I try to
>   arrange for this?

Of course you can try. If you have worked out well the past three months, it's possible that they don't want/need you full time, yet would consider keeping you around for a few months more.

> If the startup DOES offer me a full time position can I still ask for
>   three months only?

Of course you can ask. It's possible that in spite of the fact that the company wants you full time, they may be willing to settle for three months.

You can ask anything. And if you are really valuable, they may be willing to give you what you are looking for. The only way you will know is to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. Is it OK to mention the corporate job in NYC? So they know the reason why I do not want to take the full time offer?

Comment: Yeah another reason why I want to stay at the company longer, since I will get my final review in a couple of weeks, I want to make sure I have a job during the interview process at the fortune 500. Thanks!